# Show only the_title() in my sidebar.php

Tags: php, wordpress

The way the site is laid out is like this (just so you get a representation)

```
----------------------------------
| Name of the Work               |
----------------------------------
| Our Work | the content         |
|          |                     |
|          |                     |
|          |                     |
|          |                     |
|          |                     |
|          |                     |
|          |                     |
-----------------------------------
```

Now, the name of the work & the content works fine, however my sidebar ("Our Work") does not work. What I mean is, sidebar.php does show but the list of the_title only shows me the title on which page I am on.

For example if I am on ProjectA, then under "our work" it will only show ProjectA. The same goes for ProjectB, ProjectC etc..

The code I am currently using is this:

```
<?php if (have_posts()):; ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>    
    <ul>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><li><?php the_title(); ?></li></a>
    <ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I have used query_posts( 'posts_per_page=x' ); but what ends up happening is the_content shows other posts's the_content which I do not want!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about WordPress and should be on WordPress Answers http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: side note: The `a`-tag needs to be inside the `li`. `a` is not a valid child of `ul`. Other than that, I suppose you'll just need to google around what function you should use?!

Comment: How are you creating the query? or are you just throwing it in the main page While Loop?

Comment: @adamdehaven shouldnt then all wordpress questions be on wordpress.stackexchange.com, why would stackoverflow have a pretty popular tag for wordpress ? i think the question is valid and on-topic :)

Comment: I agree @DavidChase, he has posted a code example with a specific question and tagged it appropriately.  It could technically go to here or there, but either is the right place for such a question.

Comment: @daniel it's in sidebar.php & just throwing it in

Comment: @DavidChase - I wasn't saying his question was bad; just indicating the proper venue. Typically, users with questions on WordPress and WordPress-related tags, PHP, etc. will get quicker & more targeted responses from the designated community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are currently using for the loop is basically the main loop for the page.  Its not querying a specific set of posts.  You need to include some arguments for it.  Try the below loop:

```
<ul>
<?php 
    $query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'ASC'));
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
?>

    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<ul>
```

A couple things to note.  Your `<ul></ul>` tag needs to be outside the loop, otherwise you will include a new `<ul></ul>` for each item inside the loop.  You just need to create new list items, but not entirely new lists.

In the line `'post_type' => 'post'` you can change `post` to the name of any post type you would like.  `post` will just query the main "Posts" in your WP admin.

I also corrected the html syntax for your `<li></li>` that is inside the loop.

This loop will not alter the main loop, but rather create a new loop for you to display your chosen content.